# Inversion with 'neither...nor' & 'not only...but also': special occasions

Tags: grammar

I'm studying inversion and fronting in English and these two questions popped up in my head that I couldn't find an answer to.

1. Should I use inversion when using *neither...nor* with imperatives?

Which one is grammatically correct?

a. Neither will you go there nor (will you) give her a call.

b. Neither go there nor call her.

2. Is inversion grammatically compulsory when we use *not only...but (also)* structure? If yes, can we use it in spoken English I mean is it common in everyday conversation by native speakers to skip inversion here?

Are both of these sentences correct? I know 1 is correct I'm struggling with 2.

a. Not only **are they** noisy, but they're rude.

b. Not only **they are** noisy, but they're rude.

Thanks

Comment: I think that "You will neither go there nor call her." would be the most common phrasing of your first sentence... Dropping the "you will" makes it less of a command, even if it's implied.

Comment: Thank you though you actually rephrased the sentence. My question is about the grammaticality. Are you suggesting that the two sentences are not used and common and sound unnatural? **Edit**: I put the second "will you" within brackets.

Comment: I didn't rephrase your sentence... I merely added "you will" before the B version... I think it's sort of opinion-y of where "option a" is common or not. I could certainly imagine someone from the 1800s saying it but I have a difficult time hearing it in modern English outside of someone who speaks extremely formally. Others may disagree... perhaps it's really common in BrE, for example.

Comment: Imperatives use the plain form of the verb, so no inversion. So your example 1a is not imperative, but a directive. 1b is an imperative and is fine. Fronted "not only" triggers inversion, so your example 2a is correct, but not 2b. And yes, we would use inversion in everyday conversation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use inversion with imperatives, because inversion involves changing the standard order of subject/verb to verb/subject. Imperatives don't have an explicit subject (although "you" is implied) so there's nothing to invert. So, example "b" is correct: "Neither go there nor call her."

In your second question, yes, you invert after "not only", so "a" is correct  (Not only are they noisy, but they're rude.). The non-inverted example "b" sounds very strange to me.